# Как исправить ошибку error C2660?

Tags: c

```
Код:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS_
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 
int main() {
    double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, P, s;
    freopen_s ("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen_s ("output.txt",  "w", stdout);
    scanf_s("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &x1, &x2, &x3, &y1, &y2, &y3);
    a = sqrt((x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1));
    b = sqrt((x3 - x2) + (y3 - y2));
    c = sqrt((x3 - x1) + (y3 - y1));
    P = a + b + c;
    s = sqrt((P / 2)*((P / 2) - a)*((P / 2) - b)*((P / 2) - c));
    printf_s("%lf%lf", P, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Рекомендую искать код ошибки на сайте MSDN. В данном случае стоит ознакомиться с [Compiler Error C2660](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek13fhc1.aspx). Ваша ошибка: `The function is called with an incorrect number of parameters.` Исправьте функцию `freopen_s` И поскольку вы используете `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS_`, можно изменить функцию на `freopen`.
Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Функция `freopen_s` принимает первым параметром FILE**, у вас даже вызов неправильный.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, ткнуть туда, где и что надо исправить? :(

Comment: @Екатерина Павловна Комарова: Но ответ выше как раз это и делает: тыкает туда, где надо исправить, и объясняет, что именно надо исправить. Или вам нужно рассказать, в каком порядке клавиши на клавиатуре нажимать?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> errno_t freopen(   
>    FILE** pFile,  
>    const char *path,  
>    const char *mode,  
>    FILE *stream   
> );
> ```
>
> MSDN

В вашем случае будет как-то так:

```
FILE *in, *out;
freopen_s (&in, "input.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen_s (&out, "output.txt", "w", stdout);
```